# Is there a way to center on a event in Strategic View?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

The title says it all but to clarify:

When in normal view, the screen will recenter on a battle action which is nice but I like playing in strategic view and while you get the notification at the top it would be nice for it to center in on the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the only way you can get the strategic mode view to recenter on events is when they generate a notification that you can click on.

The only way to tell when a unit has been in a battle but not been killed (being killed causes a popup notification) is by paying attention to the white-text notifications which appear at the top of the screen.

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not possible to do so.